# Reincarnating with gold talents

Tags: game-of-thrones-ascent

If I reincarnate to another house and choose a gold fealty talent for my permanent point, will I be able to train the other 7 levels using normal points or will I have to repeatedly reincarnate for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to repeatedly reincarnate - each reincarnation just gives you the one point, it doesn't "unlock" the talent.

More on the wiki [here](http://gotascent.wikia.com/wiki/Permanent).

Comment: Cheers, pal. :)